# After displaying div button takes to new page

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, css

I am displaying div's on click of button and the code is working fine, the code is as follow

```
<div id="div1" class="question">1</div>
<div id="div2" class="question">2</div>
<div id="div3" class="question">3</div>
<div id="div4" class="question">4</div>
<div id="div5" class="question">5</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

the function is as follow

```
 $('#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5').hide();
var idx = 0;
$('#next').click(function () {
idx++;
if (idx < $('.question').length) $('.question').hide();
$('.question').eq(idx).show();
});
```

The problem is, once I go to the last div I want to click on the next button and it should take me to the next page, How would i do that? 
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
 $('#div2, #div3, #div4, #div5').hide();
 var idx = 0;
 $('#next').click(function() {
    idx++;
    if (idx < $('.question').length) {
      $('.question').hide();
      $('.question').eq(idx).show();
    }
    else {
       location.href = "https://www.example.com" /* add here the URL of the next page */
    }
 });
```

Comment: why I didn't think about that, I am new to html and Java, I was trying to create some complicated solutions lol Thanks so much

Comment: @bloodie Glad I was able to help :)